# How to override template block from a twig extension?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to override a template block from a twig extension? How do I do it?

**Edit:**

I have a block in my master layout template, it is called **{% block emailMenu %}**, the question is, is it possible to override this block, not from another template but from inside a twig custom function?

I guess I'm confused as the best way to handle my situation, my email menu will change from page to page depending on several factors, and I thought of making a twig function to be called from the layout or from another template, the reason I am thinking along these lines is to keep my other templates free from a lot of logic, logic that I'd rather have with pure PHP. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just render additional controller (not a twig extension) which renders own template (possibly dependent on the page), which overrides base template block.

I think, overriding block from twig extensions - it is not the twig purposed for.

Answer (score -2):

You must create a base template:

```
{# src/BW/MainBundle/Resources/views/Main/base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Test Application{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then extends parent template with `extends` keyword:

```
{# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'BWMainBundle:Main:base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My cool blog posts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for entry in blog_entries %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) docs about templating in `Symfony` using `Twig`.

Comment: You are overriding from a template, I would like to know if it's possible to override from a twig extension, more exactly from within my custom twig functions.

Comment: Why are you simply do not use another name to your function, and you don't need to override them?